# How do I graph a value for a time range (without repeating time on the x axis)

Tags: excel, plot

I am trying to graph the following information using a bar graph:

```
Drift       density Time    
0,23048397  12:00   15:00
0,053393365 15:00   18:00
0,433287679 16:00   19:00
0,129268147 17:00   20:00
0,656067688 18:00   21:00
0,356133746 19:00   22:00
0,083351634 20:00   23:00
0,167938106 21:00   00:00
```

The values on the first column = Y-Axis
So I would like 12:00 - 15:00 to be the first value on the X Axis plotted against the Y-Axis value 0,23048397 (as a bar).

The problem is: I don't want the next Y-Axis value 0,053393365 (as a bar) to represent 15:00 - 18:00. Why? Because the time '15:00' will show twice.

In other words, I have only managed the X-Axis to be:

```
 12:00-15.00 ... 15:00-18:00....18:00-21:00
```

How can I make two of the x-axis 3 hour intervals share one common hour?
12:00-15:00-18:00-21:00 (and have the pertaining Y axis values side-by-side each other?)

I hope the description wasn't too complicated. Would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you want in a portable manner (i.e. without creating a box with all of the names and then adjust its position and size) using Excel alone. You can get similar effect via appending hyphens to the first time column (see the screenshot - made in Gnumeric, but should look alike in Excel). This solution is not scalable, meaning that you have to adjust the width of the plot and/or font of the labels to decrease the distance between the labels to minimum.
- If this is a one-time task, I'd correct the labels in a vector image editor.
- If you have to produce such plots on a regular basis or even massively, I'd take any of the tools/libraries for plotting, capable of producing SVG-files, and then adjust the labels by a tiny script (or even integrate them in a small program or using pipes).
- It could be, that there is a ready-made `R`'ish solution, but I'm not aware of it.

[image: Made in Gnumeric, but should look alike in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

You could manage this with a slew of formulas, but they'll be a bear to maintain. There are probably easier ways.

Are the times always an integral number of hours? If so, change your data entry so you have one value per hour, repeating values if they don't change from one hour to the next.

If this is so, labeling isn't too burdensome either. It takes longer to describe than to actually do.

Start with a data range similar to the following. Your times plus one extra hour are listed in the first column, your Y values in the second, and a bunch of zeros in the third.

[image: data for easy charting]

Select the range in the heavy border and insert a column chart (Chart 1 below). Use a small value (10% here) for the gap width so the bars almost fill the hourly slots.

Select the yellow shaded hours, then hold Ctrl while selecting the yellow shaded zero values. This selects both ranges. Copy, then select the chart, then use Paste Special (Paste dropdown on the Home tab) to add the data as a new series (Chart 2 below). It deosn't show up because of the zero values, but it pushes the bars to one side.

Select the original bars, press the up arrow key to select the zero-value bars instead, click the button between alt and ctrl to the right of the space key to pop up the context menu, and select Change Series Chart Type. Select a line type. In Excel 2013 you can move the line series to the secondary axis at the same time. In other versions, format the line series so it's on the secondary axis. See Chart 3.

[image: Explanatory Charts 1-3]

Now use the plus icon in 2013 or the Chart Tools > Layout tab to add the secondary horizontal axis to the chart (Chart 4).

Format the secondary horizontal axis so it uses no line, and under Axis Options, select Axis Crosses On Tick Marks (Chart 5). This moves the first and last time labels to the outer edges of the chart, so these labels define the times between the bars, not centered under the bars.

Format the primary horizontal axis so it uses no line. Under Axis Options > Labels, choose None, to hide the original hour labels (Chart 6).

[image: Explanatory Charts 4-6]

Format the secondary horizontal axis, and under Labels, choose the Low option, to move them below the bars (Chart 7).

Finally, format the added line series so it uses no line and no markers (Chart 8). You could have done this right away, but I kept them in so you could see what I was doing.

[image: Explanatory Charts 7-8]